# How to copy one directory to a group of servers

Tags: bash, shell-script, scp

I need to copy a directory to different servers, which are listed in a text file (hostfile).

I haven't found any way to do something like this with scp

```
scp -r --hostfile ~/directory to_all@servers:~/
```

I know how to do this for one server: `scp -r directory one@server:~/`, but not for many. The number of servers varies but I use the same user name for all of them.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  Copying a directory to another server, or applying this to a group of servers?  Which part of each specifically?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried many many things but nothing to fit with scp :-/

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate what you've tried.  And also please answer my previous questions.

Comment: do not put -1 that is an interesting situation and no response seen on the web about that (no response that works)

Comment: I need to copy a directory that contain files to a group of servers @MarkSmith

Comment: What is wrong with that question??

Comment: If you don't understand my questions, please ask for an explanation. Otherwise nothing more from me until you answer them,

Comment: There's no need to restate the question in the comments. And the OP is seldom the right person to determine if a question is interesting. And there's not so much wrong with the question as there is with what you have tried, and how you react.

Comment: @MarkSmith answer:1. I do not find the way to use a file that contain list of server to fit with scp. 2. not copying a directory to another server but servers many servers. 3. I have tried scp a directory to a hostfile ... but does not fit.

Comment: Can you successfully copy a directory to ONE other server? Is the username the same on every server? How many servers are there (approximately is OK - 2 or 2000?)  Please remember to answer each of these questions.

Comment: Yes I can scp -r directory one@server:~/ just works fine

Comment: Yes the username is the same ... (root)

Comment: number  of server (unknown) the list (hostfile) is moving by edition

Comment: @aurelien please [edit] your question to include this extra information. It is all too easy for it to get lost in the comments.

Comment: Your question has simply been [put on hold](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). This is not necessarily bad and it costs you no points. You just needed to [edit] it to clarify and answer the questions you were asked in the comments. As soon as you edit, it will be placed in the reopen queue and can be reopened if 5 users vote to do so. In the meantime, I have clarified your edit and reopened.

Comment: Thanks for your help @terdon That is right that I am not very clear when I say something. I have to works on that point like I have to use shellcheck on my script -_-'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is with a shell `for` loop.  For example:

```
for s in server1 server2 server3 ... serverN ; do 
    scp -r directory/ $s:~/
done
```

A minor variation is to list the servers in a file (e.g. `server-list.txt`), one per line, and do something like this:

```
for s in $(cat servers.txt) ; do 
    scp -r directory/ $s:~/
done
```

Yet another minor variation supports `#` comments (including commenting-out server hostnames) in the `servers.txt` file:

```
for s in $(sed -e 's/#.*//' servers.txt) ; do 
    scp -r directory/ $s:~/
done
```

There are countless other ways that the list of servers can be obtained or generated - e.g. run a `mysql` or `psql` query to extract the list from a database, fetch a `text/plain` file from a web server, fetch a `json` file from a web server and parse it with `jq` or `python -mjson.tool`, and many more.  The basic method remains the same.

---

If you need to do this frequently with different files/directories and/or need to run shell commands in parallel on multiple servers at the same time, I'd strongly recommend installing the [pdsh](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/pdsh.html) package and making use of the `pdcp` (parallel distributed copy) and `pdsh` (parallel distributed shell) commands.  `pdsh` is packaged for most distros.

Search here for `pdsh` - there are several questions and answers that mention it.

Answer (score 2):

```
while read server; do scp -r ~/directory to_all@$server: ; done < hostfile
```

assuming your remote user is *really* called `to_all`, and assuming you already have ssh keys set up (otherwise it would ask for a password for each of the servers).